# AngularJS - Why select drop down doesn't have $event on change

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am newbie to AngularJS. I have a question, why does `ng-change` doesn't passes the $event?

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="foo">
    <select ng-model="item" ng-options="opts as opts.name for opts in sels" ng-change="lstViewChange($event)" ng-click="listViewClick($event)"></select>
</div>
```

Script

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
angular.element(document).ready(function() {
   angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
});

function foo($scope) {
    $scope.sels = [{id: 1, name: 'a'}, {id: 2, name: 'b'}];

    $scope.lstViewChange = function($event){
        console.log('change', $event); //undefined
    }

    $scope.listViewClick = function($event){
        console.log('click', $event); //object
    }
}
```

Have a look at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/QfZZH/. `Click` passes a valid $event but `change` doesn't. Can someone explain this behavior?

Answer (score 5):

Just to state the obvious, the docs say that `ngClick` will pass the event, but `ngChange` has no such documentation.

So, what you're asking is why Angular's designers chose to do this? My thought is that `ngClick` fires as a result of a click, so it make sense that there would be a mouse event associated with the directive firing. `ngChange` on the other hand is a result of any user action that changes the model, which could be associated with all sorts of events rather than one specific event.