# How to achieve this condition (ng-change="myFunction($event)") in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have searched a lot.

here are the links I found, but I could not solve my problem.

[Passing arguments to ngChange event call from inside directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14710392/passing-arguments-to-ngchange-event-call-from-inside-directive)

[AngularJS - Why select drop down doesn't have $event on change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18555425/angularjs-why-select-drop-down-doesnt-have-event-on-change)

I have a simple Function defined in the scope like this :

```
  app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', '$sce', function ($scope, $sce) {
        $scope.MyFunction = function($event) {
                 // do stuff
        };
    }]);
```

And I have this html

```
<div ng-app="MyApp" id="ngApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl" style="display:none">
 <select class="form-control" name="selectedShowVariantsOption" ng-model="selectedShowVariantsOption" ng-options="option.name for option in options" ng-change="MyFunction($event)"></select>
</div>
```

I understand that in AngularJS you can not pass the $event to the ng-change in select. However you can do that with the on-click. I still missing what the reason behind this? also any work around to pass the $event in the ng-change ?

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: ng-change does not register any event unlike other handlers, it just pushed the function to view change listeners. Why do you need event in ngChange?

Comment: actullay, I am preventing the defualt using this code :  $event.preventDefault(), also this function is being called from link, so I am using it to get the url like this :  var url = $event.target.href;

Comment: prevent default on ngChange?

Comment: not for ngChange, for link clicking

Comment: For link why do you need ng-change? ng-change is for form inputs

Comment: no this function is being called twice, I am reusing the fucntion. Once from on-change another one from on-click in a link.

Comment: Then just do `if($event){$event.preventDefault(); }` inside `MyFunction`. Does that work?

Comment: Everyone, i am having the same issue, if you have the answer please let me know.

Comment: $event is undefined for me for some reasons. My select is a dynamic select,i am not sure if that is the reason ?